# Choosing Google account for Android C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I have a problem with C2DM service. Given that there is more than one Google account loged on the device I would like my application to choose one of these accounts to register to C2DM with (You know using preferences). Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Look at the Chrome to Phone application (http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/). There they build a list of accounts from the String array generated like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> accountNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (account.type.equals("com.google")) {
            accountNames.add(account.name);
        }
    }

    String[] result = new String[accountNames.size()];
    accountNames.toArray(result);
```

Comment: You're right. They're using the AccountManaget.getAuthToken(). Good job.

Comment: But how to specify the selected account in your REGISTER intent?

Comment: @MarcusWolschon: You can either just choose any one of these accounts and use that to register or even better (again looking at the chrometophone application) show a dialog asking the user to choose which account should be used for registering...

Comment: @Kasium Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");

registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));

registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", aliasEmailUsedAtSignup);

context.startService(registrationIntent);

Where do you put the selected account in this code?

Comment: @MarcusWolschon Sorry, it is been along time since I looked at C2DM. Not sure... But I still advise to checkout ChromeToPhone's code.

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some thought I think it just does't work this way. All the C2DM needs is 'existing connection' and I think there is only one connection no matter how many google accounts there are.